# How to get context / line number in ANTLR 4 parser rule?

Tags: antlr4

Take this rule / catch for example:

```
section : (title sstart row+ send);

    catch[Exception e] {System.out.println("Notification: Problem on line " + *line # here*); System.exit(0);}
```

How could I get the line number of the token that threw the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look in the generated code where your exception block is placed, you will see that it is part of a method that is meant to parse the `section` rule, probably something like:

```
public final SectionContext section() throws RecognitionException {
    SectionContext _localctx = new SectionContext(_ctx, getState());
    ...
}
```

As you see there's a parse context (`_localctx`) created for this rule, which will get all sub contexts along with references to the first and last token that make up this rule (see `ParserRuleContext.start` and `ParserRuleContext.stop`. This is where you can get the source info from.

It could be that this `SectionContext` instance is not yet finish at the time of the exception. In that case you can use the parent context instead (the `_ctx` parameter in the `SectionContext` creation call).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ParserRuleContext ctx, you can know the line as:

```
ctx.start.getLine()
```

And you can know the position in line:

```
ctx.start.getCharPositionInLine()
```